# Scroll snap but using anchor tags on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I try to set **scroll snap** in place. What I try to achieve can be seen here: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage. So when user start scrolling, it is immediately intercepted and page is scrolled until the next section.

I cannot use the plugin provided on this link because they use div with `section` class but I cannot edit this kind of html elements.

I prefer using the `id` on the anchor tags on the page. So when user starts scrolling up/down I need to detect the previous/next anchor and scroll to it.

As showed on the link demo above, when the (mouse) scrolling begins (up or down), nothing can stop it... until it stopped. Then again another scroll can occurs.

I can easily detect mouse scroll up or down thanks to the following code:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
       console.log('down');
   } else {
      // upscroll code
      console.log('up');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

I can also detect whether a scroll is in progress like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
   $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    // do something
    console.log("Haven't scrolled in 250ms!");
   }, 250));
});
```

Now I need to **really** scroll to the next/previous anchor (thanks to [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/))

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f38fmsw9/1/

Open the console and check messages when scrolling up/down/stop.

Many thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot use the plugin provided on this link because they use div
>   with section class but I cannot edit this kind of html elements.

Why don't you use the fullpage.js option `sectionSelector` to change that and use any other selector?

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionSelector: '.mySelector'
});
```

Then in the HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="mySelector">Section 1</div>
    <div class="mySelector">Section 2</div>
    <div class="mySelector">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

You can even use things such as the following in case you don't have a common class for all the sections:

```
sectionSelector: '#fullpage>div'
```

Any jQuery valid selector will be allowed.

> I prefer using the id on the anchor tags on the page. So when user
>   starts scrolling up/down I need to detect the previous/next anchor and
>   scroll to it.

I would say using `id` elements will be probably quite difficult, as the site will scroll to the given ID before you can even control the animation. 
It is a browser feature.